# Function and Pointers to find the amplitude (largest value) of a signal in an array

Tags: c++

my lecturer created this function in a live code clinic and I am trying to copy it out then re-write it multiple times until I have learnt and understood the code.

Currently I'm unsure where I need to define the "findgreatest" function for the program to run. I was under the impression that you had to define functions within the main(). However, there are likely more errors I'm not seeing. Anyways, some help to get this code running and explained in more detail would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Alex

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    const unsigned int size = 15;            // creates a const int for array
    int a_sig [size];                        // assigns int to array size

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {        
        a_sig[i] = rand() % 100;                 
        cout << *(a_sig+i) << endl;             
    }

    int findgreatest (int size, int a_sig) {  //"F deceleration not allowed"
        int max = -1;                           
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {         
            if (*(a_sig+i) > max){
                max = *(a_sig+i);
            }
        }
        return max;
    };


    int maximum;

    maximum = findgreatest(size, a_sig);     //"undeclared identifier" 

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Move your function declaration before `main()`. You cannot define functions inside another function's body unless you use a lambda function. But syntax for the latter is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently I'm unsure where I need to define the "findgreatest" function for the program to run. I was under the impression that you had to define functions within the main().

Actually, you **cannot** define named functions in main. You can see this in the error `declaration not allowed`.

Functions must be declared before use. During compilation, the compiler will note where functions are defined. When the compiler sees one of these functions called, it knows what instructions to put since it is aware that these functions exist. But if a function isn't declared (and defined), then the compiler cannot interpret function calls.

You should either define your function before main, or declare your function before main and define it after main.

#### Option: Defining function before main

If you want to define the function before main, your code might look like

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>  // rand is defined here
using namespace std;

// Defines findgreatest
// findgreatest is now available for use later in program
int findgreatest (int size, int a_sig[]) // I added a `[]` in this signature
{
    int max = -1;                           
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {         
        if (*(a_sig+i) > max){
            max = *(a_sig+i);
        }
    }
    return max;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    const unsigned int size = 15;            // creates a const int for array
    int a_sig [size];                        // assigns int to array size

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {        
        a_sig[i] = rand() % 100;                 
        cout << *(a_sig+i) << endl;             
    }

    int maximum;
    maximum = findgreatest(size, a_sig);

    // You probably want to do something with the maximum?
    cout << "\nMaximum is " << maximum << endl;

    return 0;
} // (I removed an unnecessary semicolon here)
```

#### Option: Declaring function before main, define after

Alternately, you can declare the function (i.e. give a description of its name and signature) and define it later. You can do this with

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

// declares findgreatest
// The compiler knows that this function is defined somewhere and can make
// references to it. If the definition isn't also provided during compilation,
// an error is raised.
int findgreatest (int size, int a_sig[]);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    const unsigned int size = 15;            // creates a const int for array
    int a_sig [size];                        // assigns int to array size

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {        
        a_sig[i] = rand() % 100;                 
        cout << *(a_sig+i) << endl;             
    }

    int maximum;
    maximum = findgreatest(size, a_sig);

    // You probably want to do something with the maximum?
    cout << "\nMaximum is " << maximum << endl;

    return 0;
}
// Definition
int findgreatest (int size, int a_sig[])
{
    int max = -1;                           
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {         
        if (*(a_sig+i) > max){
            max = *(a_sig+i);
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

#### Additional notes

1. To use `rand()`, you need to `#include <cstdlib>`.
2. You compute maximum but don't do anything with it. I added a statement outputting this to the terminal at the end of main.
3. I removed a semicolon after `main(){}`.
4. Your function signature `findgreatest(int size, int a_sig)` isn't quite right. The second argument is an array, not an int. There are a few different ways to denote this, but I changed it to `findgreatest(int size, int a_sig[])` to indicate to the compiler that it should be expecting an array.

When you learn more about arrays, you'll know a bit more about that. And you'll probably revisit the expressions `*(a_sig + i)`, which are a bit odd.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

I used the first example you gave and got it working! (now to copy it out a million times)